# How to detect NFC in multiple Activities?

Tags: android-activity, nfc, android-pendingintent

Do we still need SETUP NfcAdapter, PendingIntent and enableForegroundDispatch in every Activity?

Comment: [Example](https://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/source/browse/Android%20NFC/src/com/antares/nfc/client/NfcReaderActivity.java)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. A simple way to do it is to define a BaseNfcActivity class, where you set this up. For all Activities that need it you can then extend BaseNfcActvity (instead of Activity).